# Indentation error

Tags: python, finite-element-analysis, abaqus

I receive an indentation error that I cannot figure out the reason.
The error is

```
('unexpected indent', ('C:/Hamid/Failure_index.py',15,1,'\tSDV2=xyList[0]\n')).
```

My code is

```
from abaqusConstants import *
from odbAccess import *
from visualization import *

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
out_file= 'C:\Hamid\Stochastic\Python_script_for_Monte_Carlo_simulation\Microtensile/Failure_index.dat'
fid = open(out_file,'w')
for i in range(1,50):
    odb_path = 'C:\Hamid\Stochastic\Python_script_for_Monte_Carlo_simulation\Microtensile/Microtens-'+str(i)+'_xs.odb'
    session.openOdb(name=odb_path)
    odb = session.odbs[odb_path]
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=odb)
    xyList = session.xyDataListFromField(odb=odb, outputPosition=INTEGRATION_POINT, variable=(('SDV2', INTEGRATION_POINT), ), elementSets=(' ALL ELEMENTS', ))
    SDV2 = xyList[0]
    fid.write(SDV2+'\n')
    odb.close()

fid.close()
```

Comment: check if you have a mixture of tabs and spaces

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already did that, I am only using spaces.

Comment: That is not accurate; the traceback shows a tab before `SDV2`

Comment: `\tSDV2` look at first special symbol

Comment: And to check, `python -tt yourfile.py` will cause your program to die immediately if there is a mixture of tabs and spaces.  I believe it will also tell you where the problem starts :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces in your source code, and Python's algorithm for expanding tabs to spaces causes `SDV2 = xyList[0]` to be indented 8 spaces, not 4 like the other lines in the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I am new to Python, therefore, my questions might be primitive. I really appreciate your time.